# Как выглядит реализация? "Шаблон шаблона параметризируется шаблоном шаблона"

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как выглядит реализация следующего предложения на языке с++ и вообще в каких случаях может потребоваться так делать?

> Шаблон шаблона параметризируется шаблоном шаблона.

Comment: Вопрос нормально сформируй..

Comment: Что вас не устраивает в поставленном мною вопросе?

Comment: `vector<vector<map<int,map<char,set<vector<string>>>>>>` Хотя нет, это перебор :) Вот: `vector<vector<map<string,set<int>>>>`... Эдакая матрица, в которой элементами являются отображения названий контор на множества номеров телефонов в них :)

Comment: Есть ли смысл такое делать в компилируемом языке, а не в бд?

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что удалось придумать (не делайте так на практике):

Предположим, нужно получить пару списочных объектов, которые сами имеют разные типы, но всегда хранят объекты одного типа (например, `vector<int>` и `list<int>`) (см. ListPair ниже). Для этого нужно передавать шаблонный шаблонный параметр и конкретизировать его шаблонным параметром. При это в main std::vector является шаблоном, ListPair - шаблоном шаблона, `ListPair<std::vector, std::list, int>` - конкретизацией шаблона шаблона.

Далее, если нужно получить подобным образом пару таких пар, сам ListPair будет передаваться как шаблонный шаблонный параметр, и конкретизироваться шаблонными шаблонными параметрами (см. ListPairPair). Тогда в main ListPairPair является шаблоном шаблона, ListPair является шаблоном шаблона, получается, что шаблон шаблона конкретизируется шаблоном шаблона (и еще шаблоном (vector и list) и не шаблонным типом double)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <list>
template<template<class...> class List1, 
template<class...> class List2, 
class Arg>
struct ListPair{
    List1<Arg> list1;
    List2<Arg> list2;
}; 

template<
    template<template<class...>class,
             template<class...>class, 
             class> class Pair,    
    template<class...>class List1, 
    template<class...>class List2,
    class T>
struct ListPairPair{
    Pair<List1, List2, T> pair1;
    Pair<List2, List1, T> pair2; // Типы List1 и List2 меняются местами
}; 

int main(){
   ListPair<std::vector, std::list, int> listPair;
   listPair.list1 = {4, 7, 1, 6}; // std::vector
   listPair.list2 = {1, 3, 5}; //  std::list
....
   ListPairPair<ListPair, std::vector, std::list, double> listPairPair;
   listPairPair.pair1 = listPair; // {std::vector, std::list}
   listPairPair.pair2.list1 = {1, 3, 6}; //  std::list
   listPairPair.pair2.list2 = {6, 3, 1, 18}; // std::vector
....
}
```

Реального примера с ходу придумать не могу, предположительно, может применяться при работе с кортежами (внутри библиотек). Можно попробовать поискать в исходниках boost::hana.